# Something like interface or derived class for generics

Tags: .net, vb.net, generics, interface, derived-class

I have two implementations of my business model, which is somewhat like the skeleton below.

```
Public Class Class1(Of T)
    Public Property Property1 As String
    Public Property Property2 As String
    Public Property Property3 As Decimal

    Public Sub Method1(arg1 As T, arg2 As String)

    End Sub
    Public Sub Method2(arg1 As T, arg2 As String)

    End Sub
    Public Sub Method3(arg1 As T, arg2 As String, arg3 as Integer)

    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Class1
    Public Property Property1 As String
    Public Property Property2 As String
    Public Property Property3 As Decimal

    Public Sub Method1(Of T)(arg1 As T, arg2 As String)

    End Sub
    Public Sub Method2(Of T)(arg1 As T, arg2 As String)

    End Sub
    Public Sub Method3(Of T)(arg1 As T, arg2 As String, arg3 as Integer)

    End Sub
End Class
```

The first implementation is a generic class while the second implementation has generic methods.

I want to ensure that both classes should have same properties and methods. 
A developer may add a method in one class and forget to add in the other, which I want to avoid. As the class grows bigger, it is hard to manually ensure this, as the methods may not be in the same order in both classes.

An interface doesn't work because of difference in definition due to generics (one has `(Of T)` while the other doesn't).

Similarly derived class concept doesn't work because each method will have 2 definitions exposed with same signature.

Is there a way out?

Comment: I don't understand why you want both versions of the same method.

Comment: I need to specify `T` at class level or method level.

Comment: Then just do it at class level. Why have both though?

Comment: Add a unit-test that uses reflection to verify this.

Comment: Depending on where this class will be used, it may or may not be known beforehand the type of `T`. The other requirement is to give developer flexibility to mix and match various types of `T` when calling methods or specify it once in the beginning.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen, how would adding unit tests help. Can you please explain a bit in detail.

Comment: I'll have to do it in C#, but I'll see if I can't whip up an example for you, hang on.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to fix a patch that is trying to fix a problem somewhere else.

Comment: I have seen classes in .NET library (e.g. `SortedList` etc.) which work on similar concept. And I doubt they keep the definitions in sync manually!

Comment: Things like `SortedList` have non generic versions because they are old and were created before generics were in the language. Microsoft do not try to keep them in sync though.

Comment: Here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/lassevk/f07b2deafe98da01bb5ba9f033628a53) with an example. You might want to add even more checks to make sure the methods are even more alike, for instance verifying that the generic methods doesn't have more than just `<T>`, etc. You can run this in [LINQPad](https://linqpad.net) by adding the [NUnitLite](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnitLite/) nuget package.

Comment: @Lasse Note that code only checks methods, not properties which OP also wants, but I'm sure they can take your code and add the property check too.

Comment: Yes, I should've made that clear, I decided to just focus on the methods to get a starting point done, it should be easy enough to add more validation and rules afterwards.

Comment: Though I'm still not convinced there is a need for 2 classes here.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen, seems like reflection is the way to go. Thanks for the idea! I'm thinking of adding the checks in static constructors in both classes to check the property/method signatures since my project doesn't have any unit tests and it would be a big pain creating them just for this purpose. Though it would have been better if there were some inbuilt way to do it at design-time itself.

Comment: Is the implementation of the _generic signature_ (on Class and methods) the only difference that exists between the two class versions (i.e. the method bodies are same)?  If so, using a [Custom tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/internals/custom-tools?view=vs-2019) to code-gen the second version may not be too difficult to create.  That way you only write one version and the second is automatically generated.

Comment: Yes, all the implementation is in one class and the other one is just a wrapper around it, exposing its members in a different way. So a custom tool seems like a good option. I'll give it a try and let you know.

Comment: I just seen that you responded to my question.  They changed some things in VS2017 regarding the use of the registry that invalidates what my prior link implies is the correct method to register the tool.  These days you should be creating a VSIX installer project to handle the registration.  If you have issues, let me know and I can post an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all who helped me with the problem. I ended up creating a T4 template. All other options suggested were unsuitable for various reasons.

For anyone in situation like me, this is what I did:

1. My class (class name and implementation omitted here) which has all the business implementation is somewhat like this.

```html
Public Class Class1
    Public Property Property1 As String
    Public Property Property2 As String
    Public Property Property3 As Decimal

    Public Sub Method1(Of T)(arg1 As T, arg2 As String)
        Throw New NotImplementedException
    End Sub
    Public Sub Method2(Of T)(arg1 As T, arg2 As String)
        Throw New NotImplementedException
    End Sub
    Public Sub Method3(Of T)(arg1 As T, arg2 As String, arg3 As Integer)
        Throw New NotImplementedException
    End Sub
    Public Function Function1(Of T)(arg1 As T, arg2 As String) As String
        Throw New NotImplementedException
    End Function
    Public Function Function2(Of T)(arg1 As T, arg2 As String) As List(Of T)
        Throw New NotImplementedException
    End Function
    Public Function Function3(Of T)(arg1 As T, arg2 As String, arg3 As Integer) As Decimal
        Throw New NotImplementedException
    End Function
End Class
```

2. I added a T4 Template to the project named `Class1OfT.tt` and set its properties `Build Action = None` and `Custom Tool = TextTemplatingFileGenerator`
3. Added the following code to my `Class1OfT.tt` file:

```html
<#@ template debug="true" hostspecific="true" language="VB" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text.RegularExpressions" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ import namespace="Microsoft.VisualBasic" #>
<#@ output extension=".vb" #>

'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' <auto-generated>
'     This code was generated from a template.
'
'     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
'     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
' </auto-generated>
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<#
  Const ClassName = "Class1"
#>

Option Strict On
Option Compare Text
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class <#= ClassName #>(Of T)
    Private ClsObj As <#= ClassName #>
<#
 Dim reProperty As New Regex("Public Property (?<name>\w+)(?<sig>(?: As [^=]+))", RegexOptions.Compiled Or RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
 Dim reFunction As New Regex("Public Function (?<name>\w+)(?<of>\(Of [^\)]*\))?(?<sig>\(.*\)(?: As .+)?)", RegexOptions.Compiled Or RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
 Dim reSub As New Regex("Public Sub (?<name>\w+)(?<of>\(Of [^\)]*\))?(?<sig>\(.*\))", RegexOptions.Compiled Or RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
 Dim absolutePath As String = Host.ResolvePath(ClassName & ".vb")
 Dim contents As String = IO.File.ReadAllText(absolutePath)
 contents = contents.Substring(contents.IndexOf("Public Class " & ClassName))
 contents = contents.Substring(0, contents.IndexOf("End Class"))
 contents = contents.Replace(vbTab, " ")
 For Each line As String In Split(contents, vbNewLine)
  line = Trim(line)
  If line Like "Public ReadOnly Property *" Then
#>

    <#= line #>
<#
  ElseIf line Like "Public Property *" Then
    Dim groups = reProperty.Match(line).Groups
#>

    Public Property <#= groups("name").Value #><#= groups("sig").Value.TrimEnd #>
        Get
            Return ClsObj.<#= groups("name").Value #>
        End Get
        Set(value<#= groups("sig").Value.TrimEnd #>)
            ClsObj.<#= groups("name").Value #> = value
        End Set
    End Property
<#
  ElseIf line Like "Public Function *" Then
    Dim groups = reFunction.Match(line).Groups
#>

    Public Function <#= groups("name").Value #><#= groups("sig").Value #>
        Return ClsObj.<#= GetFnDef(groups("name").Value, groups("of").Value, groups("sig").Value) #>
    End Function
<#
  ElseIf line Like "Public Sub *" AndAlso Not line Like "Public Sub New(*" Then
    Dim groups = reSub.Match(line).Groups
#>

    Public Sub <#= groups("name").Value #><#= groups("sig").Value #>
        ClsObj.<#= GetFnDef(groups("name").Value, groups("of").Value, groups("sig").Value) #>
    End Sub
<#
  End If
 Next
#>
End Class

<#+
    Function GetFnDef(name As String, ofPart As String, fnArgs As String) As String
        Static reArgName As New RegularExpressions.Regex("^\w+$", RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.Compiled)
        If fnArgs.StartsWith("(") Then fnArgs = fnArgs.SubString(1)
        Dim parts() As String = Split(fnArgs)
        Dim args = Enumerable.Range(0, parts.Length).Where(Function(n) parts(n) = "As").Select(Function(n) parts(n - 1)).ToList
        For i As Integer = args.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
            If args(i) Like "*()" Then args(i) = args(i).Substring(0, args(i).Length - 2)
            If Not reArgName.IsMatch(args(i)) Then args.RemoveAt(i)
        Next
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(ofPart) Then
            Return String.Concat(name, "(", Join(args.ToArray, ", "), ")")
        Else
            Return String.Concat(name, "(Of T)(", Join(args.ToArray, ", "), ")")
        End If
    End Function
#>
```

4. On saving the file, a new file named `Class1OfT.vb` is generated that has following code. Exactly what I need.

```html
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' <auto-generated>
'     This code was generated from a template.
'
'     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
'     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
' </auto-generated>
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Option Strict On
Option Compare Text
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Class1(Of T)
    Private ClsObj As Class1

    Public Property Property1 As String
        Get
            Return ClsObj.Property1
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            ClsObj.Property1 = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Property2 As String
        Get
            Return ClsObj.Property2
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            ClsObj.Property2 = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Property3 As Decimal
        Get
            Return ClsObj.Property3
        End Get
        Set(value As Decimal)
            ClsObj.Property3 = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub Method1(arg1 As T, arg2 As String)
        ClsObj.Method1(Of T)(arg1, arg2)
    End Sub

    Public Sub Method2(arg1 As T, arg2 As String)
        ClsObj.Method2(Of T)(arg1, arg2)
    End Sub

    Public Sub Method3(arg1 As T, arg2 As String, arg3 As Integer)
        ClsObj.Method3(Of T)(arg1, arg2, arg3)
    End Sub

    Public Function Function1(arg1 As T, arg2 As String) As String
        Return ClsObj.Function1(Of T)(arg1, arg2)
    End Function

    Public Function Function2(arg1 As T, arg2 As String) As List(Of T)
        Return ClsObj.Function2(Of T)(arg1, arg2)
    End Function

    Public Function Function3(arg1 As T, arg2 As String, arg3 As Integer) As Decimal
        Return ClsObj.Function3(Of T)(arg1, arg2, arg3)
    End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to do that in VB.  The closest thing would be to have separate interfaces for both, like this:

```
Public Interface IGenericMethods
    Sub Method1(Of T)(arg1 As T, arg2 As String)
    Sub Method2(Of T)(arg1 As T, arg2 As String)
    Sub Method3(Of T)(arg1 As T, arg2 As String, arg3 as Integer)
End Interface

Public Interface IGenericClass(Of T)
    Sub Method1(arg1 As T, arg2 As String)
    Sub Method2(arg1 As T, arg2 As String)
    Sub Method3(arg1 As T, arg2 As String, arg3 as Integer)
End Interface

Public Class GenericMethods
    Inherits IGenericMethods

    ' ...
End Class

Public Class GenericClass(Of T)
    Inherits IGenericClass(Of T)

    ' ...
End Class
```

At least then you only have those two interfaces in sync, but, as you already are aware, there's still no way to force the two interfaces to stay in sync.  The only way I can think of to do that is to add a unit test which uses reflection to compare the two interfaces and generates a failure result when they are different.  At least then you can automate the running of the unit tests so that you get immediately notified any time a change is made to one but not the other.

Alternatively, since both classes seem to do the same thing, it may make more sense to combine the two into one class:

```
Public Class Class1(Of T)
    Public Property Property1 As String
    Public Property Property2 As String
    Public Property Property3 As Decimal

    Public Sub Method1(arg1 As T, arg2 As String)
    End Sub

    Public Sub Method2(arg1 As T, arg2 As String)
    End Sub

    Public Sub Method3(arg1 As T, arg2 As String, arg3 as Integer)
    End Sub

    Public Sub Method1(Of T2)(arg1 As T2, arg2 As String)
    End Sub

    Public Sub Method2(Of T2)(arg1 As T2, arg2 As String)
    End Sub

    Public Sub Method3(Of T2)(arg1 As T2, arg2 As String, arg3 as Integer)
    End Sub
End Class
```

That still doesn't force the class to have both versions of each method, but it at least is all in the same class where it's more obvious that if you change one you have to change the other, especially if you add some comments to that effect.

One last option would be to use a code-generation tool, such as a T4 template, to autogenerate both classes from the same script.  That way, when you need to make a change, you only have to change it once, in the script, and then both classes will automatically be regenerated to match.